# Why doesn't the for loop exit when using Tcplistener incoming iterator

Tags: rust

Looking at the rust bible, there is the following code:

```
use std::net::TcpListener;

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:7878").unwrap();

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();

        println!("Connection established!");
    }
}
```

I was wondering why the for loop doesn't exit. After one iteration of the for loop (ie. if nobody connects), shouldn't the for loop finish and the main function exit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is intended. From the documentation for [`TcpListener`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpListener.html) regarding `incoming()` notes:

> The returned iterator will never return `None` and will also not yield the peer's `SocketAddr` structure. Iterating over it is equivalent to calling `accept` in a loop.

And `accept()` notes:

> This function will block the calling thread until a new TCP connection is established.

So it is designed to infinitely wait for connections and doesn't yield execution until one does.

---

You can change this behavior by calling `listener.set_nonblocking(true)` to have `accept` (and therefore the `incoming` iterator) to immediately yield with the error `io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock` if no connections are pending.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things!